# Hibernate Criteria API returned data and subquery

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api

Is it possible to operate the Criteria API on variables?
I have complicated SQL query:

```
SELECT book_id, filter_id FROM (
      SELECT ba.book_id, bf.filter_id, max(if(ba.dimension = 'device', ba.term, null)) as device
      FROM book_availability ba
      INNER JOIN book_filter bf ON bf.book_id = ba.book_id
      WHERE (
            ba.book_id IN (1234, 12345, 123456)
            OR bf.filter_id IN (1, 2)
        )
        AND bf.filter_id IN (3)
        AND (ba.date_from < '2021-06-01 23:59:59' OR ba.date_from IS NULL)
        AND (ba.date_to > '2021-06-01 23:59:59' OR ba.date_to IS NULL)
        AND ba.term IN ('web', '*')
      GROUP BY ba.book_id, bf.filter_id
  ) as subqry
WHERE (device = 'web' OR device = '*');
```

The query is dynamic and the values in the where section change.
I don't know how to solve a fragment in which I return variables like:

```
SELECT ba.book_id, bf.filter_id, max(if(ba.dimension = 'device', ba.term, null)) as device
```

```
SELECT book_id, filter_id
```

The optimal in my case would be the map(`Map<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>`): filter id - book ids list.
I understand that it is hard to use, so I try to get List which will be changed to the map.

Enities:

```
public class BookFilter {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private int bookId;
    private int filterId;

    public BookFilter(int bookId, int filterId) {
        this.bookId = bookId;
        this.filterId = filterId;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class BookAvailability {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private int bookId;
    private String type;
    private String term;
    private Instant dateFrom;
    private Instant dateTo;
}
```

Another option of query:

```
SELECT ba.book_id, bf.filter_id
FROM book_availability ba
        INNER JOIN book_filter bf ON bf.book_id = ba.book_id
WHERE (
        ba.book_id IN (1234, 12345, 123456)
        OR bf.filter_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
    )
  AND (bf.filter_id IN (6))
  AND (ba.date_from < '2021-04-16 23:28:48' OR ba.date_from IS NULL)
  AND (ba.date_to > '2021-04-16 23:28:48' OR ba.date_to IS NULL)
  AND ((ba.term = 'device' and (ba.term ='*' or ba.term='web'))
  OR (ba.term = 'country' and (ba.term ='*' or ba.term='en')))
GROUP BY bf.filter_id, ba.book_id
HAVING MAX(IF(ba.term = 'device', 1, 0)) > 0
   AND MAX(IF(ba.term = 'country', 1, 0)) > 0;
```

For now I have query

```
select distinct bf.id, bf.book_id, bf.filter_id
from book_filter bf 
cross join book_availability ba 
where 
bf.book_id=ba.book_id 
and ((ba.type in (?)) 
and (ba.term in (?) or ba.term=?) 
and (ba.date_from<=? or ba.date_from is null) 
and (ba.date_to>=? or ba.date_to is null) 
or (ba.type in (?)) and (ba.term in (?) or ba.term=?) and (ba.date_from<=? or ba.date_from is null) and (ba.date_to>=? or ba.date_to is null)) 
and (bf.book_id in (?)) 
group by bf.id , bf.filter_id , bf.book_id
```

The only thing I can't apply is:

```
HAVING MAX(IF(ba.term = 'device', 1, 0)) > 0
   AND MAX(IF(ba.term = 'country', 1, 0)) > 0;
```

Part of code:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery < BookFilter > query = cb.createQuery(BookFilter.class);
Root < BookFilter > bookFilterRoot = query.from(BookFilter.class);

List < Predicate > bookAvailabilityPredicates = new ArrayList < > ();
List < AvailabilityTerm > terms = searchParameters.getAvailabilityTerms();
List < Predicate > predicates = new ArrayList < > ();
if (terms != null) {
    Root < BookAvailability > bookAvailabilityRoot = query.from(BookAvailability.class);
    bookAvailabilityPredicates = terms
        .stream()
        .map(term - >
            cb.and(
                cb.and(bookAvailabilityRoot.get("type").in(term.getType()),
                    cb.or(bookAvailabilityRoot.get("term").in(term.getTerms()), cb.equal(bookAvailabilityRoot.get("term"), "*"))
                ),
                cb.or(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(bookAvailabilityRoot.get("dateFrom"), term.getDate().toInstant()), cb.isNull(bookAvailabilityRoot.get("dateFrom"))),
                cb.or(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(bookAvailabilityRoot.get("dateTo"), term.getDate().toInstant()), cb.isNull(bookAvailabilityRoot.get("dateTo")))
            ))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    query.groupBy(bookFilterRoot.get("id"), bookFilterRoot.get("filter_id"), bookFilterRoot.get("book_id"));
    predicates.add(cb.equal(bookFilterRoot.get("book_id"), bookAvailabilityRoot.get("book_id")));
    Predicate bookAvailabilityPredicate = cb.or(bookAvailabilityPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    predicates.add(bookAvailabilityPredicate);
}

if (filterIds != null) {
    predicates.add(bookFilterRoot.get("filter_id").in(filterIds));
}

query.select(bookFilterRoot).where(cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0])));

entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Comment: What did you try so far? It shouldn't be too hard to model this query with the JPA Criteria API. You can't use a subquery in the FROM clause, but you actually don't even need that. You could just use the HAVING clause for the outer queries restriction.

Comment: Due to the inability to implement the previous query, I am currently trying to implement it as in the query added at the end. I find it very difficult to do book_availability dynamic.

Comment: Since you are not sharing the code you are using it's hard to help you.

Comment: In my free time I will insert what I managed to get and how I remodeled.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov I added what I have for that moment